# Import Error: No module named wintypes ( maven )

Tags: python, maven, ctypes, pyautogui

I am new in python / maven,
I wrote python library which I use in robot framework. I have to import file in website where is no input field. So I used **selenium library** to click 'browser' button and next the popup is opened. To find and import the file I used **pyautogui** module:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.typewrite(file)
pyautogui.typewrite(['down'])
pyautogui.typewrite(['enter'])
```

Everything works in robot framework, but when I want to run it in maven, svn project then I get the error:

> Import Error: No module named wintypes

**pyautogui** module use the **ctypes** module where is **wintypes** method.

Do you know what is wrong? Maybe should I add some dependencies to pom.xml?

Comment: If you're running on a POSIX platform, `ctypes.wintypes` may not be included in the distribution. It can't be imported on a non-Windows system anyway.

Comment: I run it on Windows.
As I told.. everything works, except one case - when I add the code to maven project.